# Fabric.js stop responding in chrome at start

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fabricjs

I have created a photo editor using fabric.js, but when I launch my web page at localhost and add a photo to the canvas, the resizing and movements of the photo don't respond at all. But when I click "Inspect element" and close it, everything starts working normally. I don't understand what's the problem here? Every timec I have to open "Inspect element" once to make canvas respond.

A little help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have came across the same problem. My work around is:

- After adding the element to the canvas, render the canvas by doing:
  canvas.renderAll();
- Then calculate the offset by doing:
  canvas.calcOffset();

It works for me.